# How do I parse an .ost file into separate emails (preferably with Python)

Tags: python, email, ubuntu, archive, pst

I am currently trying to parse a .ost file into individual items & emails. I have used libpst to accomplish this for .pst files however this doesn't seem to support .ost's. My operating system is Ubuntu Server 16.04. Any and all suggestions are very welcome!!!

For pst files: `sudo readpst -o  -D -j 4 -r -u -w -m`

Comment: You can try the libpff library here - https://github.com/libyal/libpff/wiki

Answer (score 2):

I have parsed pst and ost files using Libpff's Python binding called [Pypff](https://github.com/libyal/libpff/wiki/Python-development). It was able to parse the ost file I had given as input. 
 
You can have a look at my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53301761/10351455) on how to Export PST and OST with pypff / libpff for a detailed description.