# Extract text from a .PST file

Tags: python, pst

I am trying to extract the content (as a string/text) of a `.pst` file.

I tried different answers but I did not find any relevant solution.

[Outlook PST File Parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197388/outlook-pst-file-parsing-in-python)

[Read PST files from win32 or pypff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217082/read-pst-files-from-win32-or-pypff)

[Export PST and OST with pypff / libpff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012454/export-pst-and-ost-with-pypff-libpff)

I am mostly focused on the library **libpff** (https://github.com/libyal/libpff) but I do not think the library is helpful to extract the text of a pst.

My code:

```
import pypff
pst = pypff.file()
pst.open("my_pst_file.pst")
```

The code opens the pst, but I do not see how I can extract its content as txt.

Comment: have use pywin32?

Comment: Not yet, I am gonna take a look. Thanks.

Comment: look this : https://gist.github.com/kevthehermit/40ff03e3adc524ece04f735e68be43c2

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use `pypff` to extract text. I followed this link too ([Export PST and OST with pypff / libpff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012454/export-pst-and-ost-with-pypff-libpff)).

The `pypff.file()` can be confusing since the developer didn't provide a decent document of every function and attribute for instructions. Took me a while to explore it myself.

Here is what I did recently.

```
# path to your pst file
opst = pypff.open(path)
root = opst.get_root_folder()

# 3 subfolders, for me, only 2nd one has content
# Use 'root.get_number_of_sub_folders()' to see which folder is blank
folder = root.get_sub_folder(1)
# 2 subfolders, the 2nd one is my inbox
inbox = folder.get_sub_folder(1)

# mail count in current folder
count = inbox.get_number_of_sub_items()

# Example of extracting info from one email
msg = inbox.get_sub_item(0)

subject = msg.subject
content = msg.plain_text_body.decode()
sender = msg.sender_name
header = msg.transport_headers
sent_time = msg.delivery_time

if msg.number_of_attachments > 0:
    # read from attachment 1
    size = attachment = msg.get_attachment(0).get_size()
    attachment_content = (msg.get_attachment(0).read_buffer(attach_size)).decode('ascii', errors='ignore')
```

For those who want to use `pypff`, don't use pip install. It only builds from version 20161119, which crashes a lot for me.

Build from newer version on their [website](https://github.com/libyal/libpff/wiki/Building#using-setuppy). There's a `setup.py`, it should be easy to build.

For attachments, `ascii` decoder is not ideal. I have tried [all 98 decoders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728376/get-a-list-of-all-the-encodings-python-can-encode-to) in python3, and none can decode every byte. Which means, a **single** method cannot decode all. In my case, `utf_16` can extract the content, which is good enough for me.